# Make sure ProcessingQueue.Count correct in multiple threading application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a windows service to process xml files in the linked list queue. The files in the queue were added by FileSystemWatcher event when files created.

```
namespace XMLFTP
{
    public class XML_Processor : ServiceBase
    {
       public string s_folder { get; set; }
       public XML_Processor(string folder)
       {
           s_folder = folder;
       }
       Thread worker;
       FileSystemWatcher watcher;
       DirectoryInfo my_Folder;
       public static AutoResetEvent ResetEvent { get; set; }
       bool running;
       public bool Start()
       {
           my_Folder = new DirectoryInfo(s_folder);
           bool success = true;
           running = true;
           worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServiceLoop));
           worker.Start();
           // add files to queue by FileSystemWatcher event
           return (success);
       }
       public bool Stop()
       {
           try
           {
               running = false;
               watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
               worker.Join(ServiceSettings.ThreadJoinTimeOut);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               return (false);
           } 
           return (true);
       }
       public void ServiceLoop()
       {
           string fileName;
           while (running)
           {
               Thread.Sleep(2000);
               if (ProcessingQueue.Count > 0)
               {
                   // process file and write info to DB. 
               }
           }
       }

       void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
       {
           switch (e.ChangeType)
           {
               case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:// add files to queue
           }
       } 
    }
 }
```

There might be a thread safe problem.

```
        while (running)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            if (ProcessingQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                // process file and write info to DB. 
            }
        }
```

As the access to ProcessingQueue.Count isn't protected by a lock, the Count can change, if a different thread alters the "queue". As result the process file part may fail. That's also the case if you implement the Count property as:

```
public static int Count
{
get { lock (syncRoot) return _files.Count; }
}
```

as the lock is released to early.

My two questions:

1. How to make ProcessingQueue.Count be correct?
2. If I use .NET Framework 4.5 [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) skills, the sample code as:

   ```
    class ConsumingEnumerableDemo
    {
       // Demonstrates: 
       //      BlockingCollection<T>.Add() 
       //      BlockingCollection<T>.CompleteAdding() 
       //      BlockingCollection<T>.GetConsumingEnumerable() 
       public static void BC_GetConsumingEnumerable()
       {
           using (BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>())
           {

               // Kick off a producer task
               Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
               {
                   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                   {
                       bc.Add(i);
                       Thread.Sleep(100); // sleep 100 ms between adds
                   }

                   // Need to do this to keep foreach below from hanging
                   bc.CompleteAdding();
               });

               // Now consume the blocking collection with foreach. 
               // Use bc.GetConsumingEnumerable() instead of just bc because the 
               // former will block waiting for completion and the latter will 
               // simply take a snapshot of the current state of the underlying collection. 
               foreach (var item in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable())
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(item);
               }
            }
          }
        }
   ```

The sample uses a constant 10 as the iteration-clause, how to apply my dynamic count in queue to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `BlockingCollection`, you don't have to know the count. The consumer knows to keep processing items until the queue is empty and `IsCompleted` is true. So you could have this:

```
var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Add 10 items to the queue
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
        queue.Add(i);

    // Wait one minute
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0));

    // Add 10 more items to the queue
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(10, 10))
        queue.Add(i);

    // mark the queue as complete for adding
    queue.CompleteAdding();
});

// consumer
foreach (var item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The consumer will output the first 10 items, which empties the queue. But because the producer hasn't called `CompleteAdding`, the consumer will continue to block on the queue. It will catch the next 10 items that the producer writes. Then, the queue is empty and `IsCompleted == true`, so the consumer ends (`GetConsumingEnumerable` gets to the end of the queue).

You can check `Count` at any time you like, but the value you get is just a snapshot. By the time you evaluate it, it's likely that either the producer or the consumer will have modified the queue and changed the count. But it shouldn't matter. As long as you don't call `CompleteAdding`, the consumer will continue to wait for an item.

The number of items that the producer writes doesn't have to be constant. For example in my [Simple Multithreading](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/07/18/simple-multithreading-part-2/) blog post, I show a producer that reads a file and writes the items to a `BlockingCollection` that's serviced by a consumer. The producer and consumer run concurrently, and everything goes until the producer reaches the end of the file.

Comment: @Love: `GetConsumingEnumerable` checks `IsCompleted`. It's a property of the `BlockingCollection` class.